# IDENTITY_INSERT está definido como OFF - Entity FrameWork Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, fluent-api, entity-framework-core

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação com [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) + [entity-framework-core](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core) e com mapeamento e configuração via [fluent-api](/questions/tagged/fluent-api).
Quando vou inserir no banco recebo o erro de que o `IDENTITY_INSERT` está definido como `OFF`.

Segue a Imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho as entidades (Que estão relacionadas):

- Material;
- Embalagem;
- Grupo Material;
- UnidadeMedida;
- Registro Anvisa;

### Código das Entidades

```
public class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
        Registros = new List<RegistroANVISA>();
    }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int NumeroMaxProcessamento { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int GrupoMaterialId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual GrupoMaterial GrupoMaterial { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int UnidadeMedidaId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual UnidadeMedida UnidadeMedida { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int EmbalagemId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Embalagem Embalagem { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IEnumerable<RegistroANVISA> Registros { get; set; }
}

public class Embalagem
{
    public Embalagem()
    {
        Materiais = new List<Material>();
    }

    public int EmbalagemId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materiais { get; set; }
}

public class GrupoMaterial
{
    public GrupoMaterial()
    {
        Materiais = new List<Material>();
    }

    public int GrupoMaterialId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materiais { get; set; }
}

public class UnidadeMedida
{
    public UnidadeMedida()
    {
        Materiais = new List<Material>();
    }

    public int UnidadeMedidaId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materiais { get; set; }
}

public class RegistroANVISA
{
    public RegistroANVISA()
    {

    }

    public int RegistroId { get; set; }
    public int NumeroRegistro { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
}
```

#### Configuração do Fluent Api

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Material> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Metrial");

    builder.Property(m => m.Descricao)
        .HasColumnType("varchar(150)")
        .IsRequired();

    builder.HasKey(m => m.MaterialId);

    builder.Property(m => m.EmbalagemId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

    builder.Property(m => m.GrupoMaterialId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

    builder.Property(m => m.UnidadeMedidaId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();


    //Define relacionamento um-para-muito 
    builder.HasOne(m => m.GrupoMaterial)
        .WithMany(m => m.Materiais)
       // .HasForeignKey(m=> m.GrupoMaterial.GrupoMaterialId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    //Define relacionamento um-para-muito 
    builder.HasOne(m => m.Embalagem)
        .WithMany(m => m.Materiais)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    //Define relacionamento um-para-muito 
    builder.HasOne(m => m.UnidadeMedida)
        .WithMany(m => m.Materiais)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    //Define relacionamento um-pra-muitos (um material com muitos registros)
    builder.HasMany(m => m.Registros)
        .WithOne(m => m.Material)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: ueh, mas você quer inserir a PK na mão?

Comment: @Barbetta - Não, até onde eu sei se os objetos estiverem completos e os relacionamentos corretos, a inserção da PK e do resto fica a cargo do entity-framework-core, correto?  
Se sim, estou tentando encontrar o que estou fazendo de errado para que isso não aconteça...

Comment: Mais ou menos. Mas o erro ali está falando que você tentou inserir uma chave primaria para o objeto `UnidadeMedida`. O padrão é OFF mesmo, isso indica que o SQLServer irá gerenciar as PK's , veja esse artigo: http://www.codigomaster.com.br/banco-de-dados/set-identity_insert-sql-server-on-off

Comment: Tente debugar e ver se antes de dar o `SaveChanges()` o objeto tem valor na chave primaria

Comment: @Barbetta - Verifiquei e antes do SaveChanges() os objetos relacionados com material possuiem as chaves primarias (uma vez que são selecionados por um dropdownlist) e chegam até o repository com suas respectivas chaves primarias. O unico que ainda não tem é a classe material que está sendo salva no banco.

Comment: Quando você está adicionando os itens ao objeto `Material` você faz como? faz 1 select no banco e preenche a propriedade `Material.UnidadeMedida` além da `Material.UnidadeMedidaId`?. Se sim ai está o problema, não precisa fazer assim. no objeto `Material` o `Material.UnidadeMedida` deve estar nulo e deve ter valor apenas no `Material.UnidadeMedidaId` se não ele tenta fazer um `Insert` em "cascata"

Comment: @Barbetta - Pergunta: Eu tenho meu objeto Material e relacionado a ele eu tenho o meu objeto Grupo de Materiais. 
Ex: Material {Descricao: "xxx", Ativo: True, GrupoMaterial: new{Id: 2,Descricao: "xxxx", Ativo: True}}

o entity-framework-core vai inserir o material e a PK ou vai inserir o material e o grupo de material?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81783/discussion-between-barbetta-and-rafael-arthur).

Comment: @Barbetta a sua orientação deu certo! Problema Resolvido!!!
Muito obrigado!